# SSIS package precedence Constraint not working for multiple expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a SSIS package in which we want to see if the DataLoadStatusID == 2 then go to the path that copies the file and deletes from the initial import folder. **This part works as expected.**

And if we load the same file again, due to duplicate values the DataLoadStatusID !=2, then go to the path where the file does not get copied or deleted. The file should remain in the initial import folder.** This is not working when I re-load the same file the DataLoadStatusID !=2 does not work.**

[image: DataLoadStatusId==2]

AND

[image: DataLoadStatusID !=2]

I tired changing the Result Set to Single Row

[image: Result Set Single Row]

Set the Result Set to DataLoadStatusID

[image: Set the Result Set]

Set the Parameter. One thing to note is that the DataLoadId is the only parameter setup in the stored procedure. **But the DataLoadStatusId is setup as a variable in the SSIS package only. DataLoadStatusID is not setup as a parameter in the Stored Porcedure.** But we have a update statement in the stored procedure.

-- If there were validation errors (not just warnings, mark the data load as failed and exit procedure

```
DECLARE @ErrorCount INT = 0
SELECT @ErrorCount = COUNT(*) from dbo.ClaimLoadValidation where DataLoadId = @DataLoadId and ValidationStatusId = 2
IF (@ErrorCount > 0)
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.DataLoad set DataLoadStatusId = 3 where DataLoadId = @DataLoadId 

    RETURN
END

-- If everything worked, mark record as successful

UPDATE dbo.DataLoad set DataLoadStatusId = 2 where DataLoadId = @DataLoadId
```

[image: Parameters]

Once I run the package it gives me below error:

"[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "execute uspLoadClaimHartford ?" failed with the following error: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done. Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly."

Comment: Did you check if `ResultSet` in your SQL Task is `None`

Comment: @Dordi It was NONE and with that DataLoadStatusId ==2 works but DataLoadStatusId != 2 didn't work. So I tried to change it to Single Row and setup the Result set along with Parameters, but does not work.

Comment: Is the problem that the value of DataLoadStatus is not being set properly based on your query or is the problem that the Precedent Constraints are not following the is/is not 2 rule?

Comment: @billinkc the issue is DataLoadStatus Precedent Constraint not working is DataLoadStatus !=2. It works fine for DataLoadStatus ==2. So not sure why DataLoadStatus !=2 does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the DataLoadStatus variable is != 2.  Maybe put a breakpoint and watch on it to check it

Comment: yes i see the database table getting updated to DataLoadStatusId = 3, so in this case the DataLoadStatusId!=2 should execute. I will try with the Breakpoint as well.